# DISCORD PY Bot isn't responding to commands, no traceback error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a feeling that the on_message function is affecting my code however I don't know how else I can define message for the chat easter eggs (the messages about moe).

My code:

```
    import discord
    from discord.ext import commands
    import asyncio
    
    client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="*" , case_insensitive=True ,status=discord.Status.idle, activity=discord.Game("Starting up..."))
    client.remove_command("help")
    
    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.do_not_disturb, activity=discord.Game("Preparing Puzzle Event"))
        print("Bot is running.")
    @client.command()
    async def hello(ctx):
      await ctx.send("Hi")
    
    @client.group(invoke_without_command=True)
    async def help(ctx):
        em = discord.Embed(title = "**Command List**" , color = ctx.author.color)
        em.add_field(name = "puzzle1", value = "Starts the first puzzle")
        em.add_field(name = "wisdom", value = "Gives wise wisdom")
        await ctx.send(embed = em)
    @client.command()
    async def wisdom(ctx):
        await ctx.send("Stan Loona")
    @client.command()
    async def clue(ctx):
        await ctx.send("Which puzzle do you want a clue for? \n *1 or *2")
    
    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        if message.author == client.user:
            return
        elif message.content.startswith('Moe'):
            await message.channel.send('Is an icon')
        elif message.content.startswith('moe'):
            await message.channel.send('Is an icon')
client.run(My token)
```

There is no traceback error, it doesn't even say the bot is online, nothing runs at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `client.process_commands` at the end of the `on_mesage` event

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # ...

    await client.process_commands(message)
```

#### Reference:

- [`Bot.process_commands`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=process_commands#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands)